# How do I extract a name from the end of a string?

Tags: r, string, text, gsub

This is my first time posting a question. I am having trouble formatting some data I have read from a json file. I am just trying to extract the name form each row. Here is an example of the first row.

```
> json_data$name[1]
[[1]]
[1] "\n        "           "\n        jim bob"
```

I have tried a number of different things I have googled and searched on here, but am not having any luck at all. I need the data to look like the following:

```
[1] jim bob
```

Everything I do seems to turn it into something like this:

```
[1] "c(\"\n        \", \"\n        jim bob\")"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `str_extract(x, "\\b[\\w\\s]+\\b(?=\"\\))")`

Comment: @CausedByMonkey  I modified the code and posted as an answer

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gsub`

```
v1 <- gsub("\n +", "", str1) 
v1[nzchar(v1)]
#[1] "jim bob"
```

If we have a `list`, then use `lapply` to loop over the `list` elements.  Consider that 'json_data$name[1]`is a`list` of many elements

```
 lapply(json_data$name[1], function(x) {
            v1 <- gsub("\n +", "", x)
             v1[nzchar(v1)]
             })
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("\n        ",           "\n        jim bob")
```

Comment: `v1 <- gsub("\n +", "", json_data$name[1])`
`v1[nzchar(v1)]`

results in

` [1] "c(\"\\n        \", \"\\n        jim bob\")" `@akrun

Comment: @CausedByMonkey  Based on the example in the data I provided, it is giving the expected.  Can you update your post with a `dput` of json_data$name[1]

Comment: @CausedBy Monkey, I think your 'name' is a `list` Try `gsub("\n +", "", json_data$name[1][[1]])`